# why beforeunload always triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, which changes when -some- elements are focused.
I want to be warned when I'm leaving the page. so I keep a flag that tells me when those elements changed.
The problem is that the alert "this page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave” - is always prompt;

```
function checkSave(){
    return PageWasChanged; // it is correct, checked
}
$(window).on("beforeunload", function (eve) {
    if (checkSave()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You're code does not have a prompt in it.

Comment: There *has* to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: @evolutionxbox: The prompt comes from the browser.

Comment: I think the form is submitted and that triggers the beforeunload event, but I can't affirm that since the code is uncomplete.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what does it mean?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude the form is never submitted. it saved through ajax as a file on the server..

Comment: So share a working example. Your shared code doesn't produce the result that you describe. The `beforeunload` event only triggers when you are about to leave the page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Answer (score 1):

`beforeunload` is not like other events. Its handler is supposed to return `undefined` (don't show the prompt) or a string (which used to be used as the text of the prompt, but isn't on modern browsers).

So:

```
$(window).on.("beforeunload", function() {
    if (!checkSave()) {
        return "You have unsaved changes.";
    }
});
```

or without jQuery:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (!checkSave()) {
        return "You have unsaved changes.";
    }
};
```